# Python files pdf rename

Tags: python, file

I have a file .pdf in a folder and I have a .xls with two-column. In the first column I have the filename without extension .pdf and in the second column, I have a value.

I need to open file .xls, match the value in the first column with all filenames in the folder and rename each file .pdf with the value in the second column.

Is it possible?

Thank you for your support
Angelo

Comment: [Minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the pandas library within python. It has a function called `pandas.read_excel` that is very useful for reading excel files. This will return a dataframe, which will allow you to use `iloc` or other methods of accessing the values in the first and second columns. From there, I'd recommend using `os.rename(old_name, new_name)`, where old_name and new_name are the paths to where your .pdf files are kept. A full example of the renaming part looks like this:

```
import os

# Absolute path of a file
old_name = r"E:\demos\files\reports\details.txt"
new_name = r"E:\demos\files\reports\new_details.txt"

# Renaming the file
os.rename(old_name, new_name)
```

I've purposely left out a full explanation because you simply asked if it is possible to achieve your task, so hopefully this points you in the right direction! I'd recommend asking questions with specific reproducible code in the future, in accordance with [stackoverflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage you to do this with a .csv file instead of a xls, as is a much easier format (requires 0 formatting of borders, colors, etc.).

You can use the os.listdir() function to list all files and folders in a certain directory. Check os built-in library docs for that. Then grab the string name of each file, remove the .pdf, and read your .csv file with the names and values, and the rename the file.

All the utilities needed are built-in python. Most are the os lib, other are just from csv lib and normal opening of files:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    #anything you have to do with the file here
    #you may need to specify what permits are you opening the file with in the open function
```